# python find index of elements functionally depending on a condition

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, list-comprehension

Say I have a list of the form:

`mylist = [5, 8, 40, 90, 3, 100, 79, 10, 10]`

I want to find the indexes of elements within 80% of the value of the maximum in the list.  I can do it with a couple of loops, but I want to learn if there is a more functional way to do it.  Here is what I have used:

```py
max_nr = max(mylist)
all_max = list(filter(lambda y : y > max_nr*0.8, mylist))
```

Is there a next step (or a single step) with `map` or `filter` which could say:  go through the list, and keep only the index of those elements which obey the constraint of being greater than a number.

I am looking for an alternative to applying a third step:

```py
    all_max_index = [mylist.index(i) for i in all_max]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way:

```
all_max_index = list(filter(lambda i : mylist[i] > max_nr*0.8, range(len(mylist))))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and then unpack index along with the number in list comprehension to get indices.

```
>>> indices = [i for i, num in enumerate(mylist) if num > max_nr * 0.8]
>>> indices
[3, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make your whole thing in one line. If you need a bigger step then let me know and I will show you!

```
>>> mylist = [5, 8, 40, 90, 3, 100, 79, 10, 10]
>>> [mylist.index(x) for x in mylist if x > (max(mylist) * (80/100))]
[3, 5]
```

Comment: This creates quadratic complexity as `list.index` traverses the list from beginning.

Comment: these days `enumerate` is mostly always the better choice